# How to delete TimeMachine Backups selectively?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, sonoma

Since Sonoma and similar versions it is no longer possible to delete TimeMachine Backups in the TimeMachine Browser directly, I think it was Mavericks or so, this was the last time possible.

I tried everything by

```
sudo tmutil …
```

the … stand for hundreds of tries.

I gave up with

```
% sudo tmutil delete -p /Volumes/.timemachine/DF1238C8-A0F6-4DCE-89A3-5F206A8CD709/2021-07-19-145612.backup/2021-07-19-145612.backup/Macintosh\ HD\ -\ Data /Volumes/.timemachine/DF1238C8-A0F6-4DCE-89A3-5F206A8CD709/2021-07-19-145612.backup/2021-07-19-145612.backup/Macintosh HD - Data: Invalid deletion target (error 22)
Total deleted: Zero KB
```

The long path after the -p you get dragging and dropping the folder to Terminal.

[image: how to delete or compact timemachine backups for one of the single users?]

To be more precise, is there a possibility to compact or manually delete old TimeMachine backups from one of the Users?

Comment: TBH, I'd recommend treating TM like a black box, with no configurable options whatsoever. Messing with it usually causes problems.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that's what I'm normally doing. Somehow the normally automatic deletion of older backup fails. That for, I'm looking for alternative solutions.

On the one hand, TM is amazing but the lack of tools for e.g. migrating it to larger disks, like important other basic maintenance functionality is a total failure/design flaw.


The man page of tmutil contains unfortunately also no examples, that's pretty bad.

Comment: Why not copy the files you need to a new place and then delete the entire snapshot interval that needs deleting? The structure on APFS is new since it takes snapshots and works very hard to not allow people to go in and surgically alter parts of a backup.

Comment: When you say "the automatic deletion of older backups fails", do you mean when the drive is full, or something else?

Comment: The tmutil command should be `sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/<TMVolume> -t <date-time>` where TMVolume is that name of the volume containing your TM backups and date-time is that name of the particular snapshot you want to delete. It deletes whole snapshot. You can't delete a folder within it.

Comment: @Gilby, thank for the hint. The backup per date-time contains two disks, an external SSD and the Macintosh HD. I want to delete only the Macintosh HD and can't figure out by man page how that works. I tried everything what makes sense to me accourding to the man page, but get only errors in return.

Comment: As in the answer from @Ezekiel, you can only delete whole backups with APFS Time Machine disks - and that means you can't delete backups from a specific source disk. The man page is confusing as it mixes commands for HFS and APFS backups. My solution is to use TM for my boot disk only and use Carbon Copy Cloner for backup of other disks - that gives me more control, but requires more configuration.

Answer (score 3):

You can no longer modify within a backup. You can delete an entire backup by selecting the backup in Finder and right clicking it to delete it. You can also delete backups in Disk Utility and with the command line.

However the individual backups are now fully immutable because they are backed by File System level disk snapshots.

Comment: Could add to your first para that entire backup snapshots can be deleted in Disk Utility or using tmutil.

Comment: @Ezekial Just wanting to confirm... for deleting backups with the Finder, do you mean: right clicking it **and selecting "Move to Trash"**, to delete it? I ask in part because I don't believe that'd be as thorough as using `tmutil` with the `delete` verb. The latter I believe would delete right away while the former only once the trash was emptied.

Comment: I believe you'll see a time machine specific UI after doing that

Comment: @Ezekiel interesting! Just tried it now myself. Found that Finder shows popup asking "Are you sure you want to delete... This item will be deleted immediately.". So looks like it is immediate. I don't see anything any more Time Machine specific however with using Finder to delete the backup. Was there more you're seeing? A difference from `tmutil delete` I'm seeing is the `com.apple.backupd.SnapshotCompletionDate` attribute isn't being removed on the backup shortly after starting. But that's insignificant AFAIK.

Comment: @LouisLangholtz Hmm, it appears I've misremembered. I remember it saying "Delete Backup" - but that being said, doing it through Finder in that manner should be perfectly effective/safe